# MySQL user can't connect from remote host

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL users with the exact same permissions, one can connect from a remote host, the other can't.  How could this be?

Here is my configuration:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE user IN ('baduser','gooduser')  AND host='%';
```

Results in:

```
Host    User        Password    Select_priv Insert_priv Update_priv Delete_priv Create_priv Drop_priv   Reload_priv Shutdown_priv   Process_priv    File_priv   Grant_priv  References_priv Index_priv  Alter_priv  Show_db_priv    Super_priv  Create_tmp_table_priv   Lock_tables_priv    Execute_priv    Repl_slave_priv Repl_client_priv    Create_view_priv    Show_view_priv  Create_routine_priv Alter_routine_priv  Create_user_priv    Event_priv  Trigger_priv    Create_tablespace_priv  ssl_type    ssl_cipher  x509_issuer x509_subject    max_questions   max_updates max_connections max_user_connections    plugin  authentication_string   password_expired
%       gooduser    *PASS1      Y           N           N           N           N           N           N           N               N               N           N           N               N           N           N               N           N                       N                   N               N               N                   N                   N               N                   N                   N                   N           N               N                       0           0           0           0               NULL            N
%       baduser     *PASS2      Y           N           N           N           N           N           N           N               N               N           N           N               N           N           N               N           N                       N                   N               N               N                   N                   N               N                   N                   N                   N           N               N                       0           0           0           0               NULL            N
```

Yet when I log in as 'baduser' from the remote host...

```
mysql -h 999.888.777.666 -u baduser -p my_db
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'baduser'@'111.222.333.444' (using password: YES)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have the wrong password for baduser - try resetting the password for that user and try again to see if that solves the issue.  I tested and I get the exact same error message and error code when using an incorrect password.  Note that you can have a different password for a user depending on what host it's connecting from.

If that doesn't work, try deleting the user and re-creating it to see if that solves it.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-password.html

Comment: I tried that but I still can't log in from the remote host.

Comment: @DarrellBrogdon If it's safe to do so, try deleting that user altogether and then re-creating it.

Comment: That worked.  Thanks!  I can't imagine what was different.

Comment: Feel free to add that as an answer if you want the reputation.

Comment: @DarrellBrogdon I've added it to this answer - thx